# Readback Data through Buffers

Tags: directx12

I am pretty new to the dx12 world. As a sample project I am trying to add 2 buffers and store the output in yet another output buffer. As apart of this debugging I am trying to see if the buffers that I am loading actually have the right values. 
Thus, once the buffer is loaded, I want to put in a fence and "read back the data uploaded" into the CPU and print out the contents of the buffer. 
After a lot of googling I thought i should use the map function in DXD12.

But I am not entirely sure how I should go about doing this. Any thoughts?

Comment: I think you can also use [ID3D12Resource::ReadFromSubresource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn914415(v=vs.85).aspx)
 it is a little simpler.

Comment: But I am trying to read out of a compute buffer. I was under the impression that ReadFromSubresource is used primarily on textures and layouts.

Comment: I never used this with `UAV` but maybe it will work, just set `DstRowPitch` and `DstDepthPitch` to buffer size (in bytes) and you will see if its work. I don't see why it shouldn't work (but maybe it don't)

Comment: I created the Input buffer with the following properties:

ThrowIfFailed(m_device->CreateCommittedResource( &defaultHeapProperties, D3D12_HEAP_FLAG_NONE, &bufferDesc,
D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_COPY_DEST, nullptr,
IID_PPV_ARGS(&m_InputBuffer1[0])));

and later on when I try to read it back as follows, the compiler throws an exception!

UINT8* pDataBegin;
m_InputBuffer1[0]->ReadFromSubresource(reinterpret_cast<void**>(&pDataBegin),5,5,0,0);
printf("The value pointed to is %d", *pDataBegin);

any idea why this is happening ?

Comment: `ID3D12Resource::ReadFromSubresource` doesn't allocate memory for you and it get pointer not pointer to pointer, so you need to allocate memory and cast `pDataBegin` to `void*` not `void**`. Remember to free allocated memory

Comment: Also i'm not sure about `D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_COPY_DEST` but i don't see whole code so can't tell if its should be this resource state.

Comment: But wouldn't it be easier if i use the Map and Unmap pair?

std::vector<UINT8> pDataBegin;
ThrowIfFailed(m_InputBuffer1[0]->Map(0, NULL, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&pDataBegin)));

but then again even this throws an error :(

Comment: What error do you get? Did you try `ReadFromSubresource`? Did you do steps pointed [on Microsoft page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn899202(v=vs.85).aspx)?

Comment: I was not able to declare my heap as type D3D12_HEAP_TYPE_READBACK. Because the second I do that, I am not able to call CreateCommitResource and even create the buffer.

If i keep the heap type DEFAULT and call Map, there is nothing returned into *pDataBegin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I made little example of how to do this.

### **Short version**

You need to allocate additional buffer with heap type `D3D12_HEAP_TYPE_READBACK` and resource state set to `D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_COPY_DEST`. Then create command list with type `D3D12_COMMAND_LIST_TYPE_COPY`. After dispatch compute shader use fence to check if buffer is ready, then copy from this buffer to buffer on `D3D12_HEAP_TYPE_READBACK` heap. Check again with fence if copying is finished and call `Map` on this buffer.

I would suggest that you stop reading here and try implement it from description above and check longer version if its still doesn't work. Copy/Past isn't the best way to learn :)

### **Longer version**

First lets create new command list.

```
ID3D12CommandQueue* copyQueue;
ID3D12CommandAllocator* copyAllocator;
ID3D12GraphicsCommandList* copyList;

D3D12_COMMAND_QUEUE_DESC descCopyQueue = {};
descCopyQueue.Flags = D3D12_COMMAND_QUEUE_FLAG_NONE;
descCopyQueue.Type = D3D12_COMMAND_LIST_TYPE_COPY;
device->CreateCommandQueue(&descCopyQueue, IID_PPV_ARGS(&copyQueue));
device->CreateCommandAllocator(D3D12_COMMAND_LIST_TYPE_COPY, IID_PPV_ARGS(&copyAllocator));
device->CreateCommandList(0, D3D12_COMMAND_LIST_TYPE_COPY, copyAllocator, nullptr, IID_PPV_ARGS(&copyList));
```

Notice type `D3D12_COMMAND_LIST_TYPE_COPY`.

Next thing is new buffer.

```
D3D12_HEAP_PROPERTIES const heapPropertiesReadback =
{
    /*Type*/                    D3D12_HEAP_TYPE_READBACK
    /*CPUPageProperty*/         ,D3D12_CPU_PAGE_PROPERTY_UNKNOWN
    /*MemoryPoolPreference*/    ,D3D12_MEMORY_POOL_UNKNOWN
    /*CreationNodeMask*/        ,0
    /*VisibleNodeMask*/         ,0
};

D3D12_RESOURCE_DESC buffersDesc = {};
buffersDesc.Dimension = D3D12_RESOURCE_DIMENSION_BUFFER;
buffersDesc.Alignment = 0;
buffersDesc.Width = sizeof( unsigned int ) * 5;
buffersDesc.Height = 1;
buffersDesc.DepthOrArraySize = 1;
buffersDesc.MipLevels = 1;
buffersDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_UNKNOWN;
buffersDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
buffersDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
buffersDesc.Layout = D3D12_TEXTURE_LAYOUT_ROW_MAJOR;
buffersDesc.Flags = D3D12_RESOURCE_FLAG_NONE;

ID3D12Resource* bufferReadback;

device->CreateCommittedResource(&heapPropertiesReadback, D3D12_HEAP_FLAG_NONE, &buffersDesc, D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_COPY_DEST, nullptr, IID_PPV_ARGS(&bufferReadback));
```

Remember to set `D3D12_RESOURCE_DESC ::Width` to size of your buffers.

Then after you `Dispatch` compute list and call `ExecuteCommandLists` on compute queue you need to use fence, copy buffer and use fence again.

```
computeQueue->Signal(fence, fenceValue);
fence->SetEventOnCompletion(fenceValue, fenceEvent);
++fenceValue;
WaitForSingleObject(fenceEvent, INFINITE);

copyList->CopyResource(bufferReadback, bufferB);
copyList->Close();
copyQueue->ExecuteCommandLists(1, (ID3D12CommandList**)(&copyList));

copyQueue->Signal(fence, fenceValue);
fence->SetEventOnCompletion(fenceValue, fenceEvent);
++fenceValue;
WaitForSingleObject(fenceEvent, INFINITE);
```

After this you can call `Map` on resource.

```
unsigned int* data;
bufferReadback->Map(0, nullptr, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&data));
```

I hope this will help, let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you for you recommendation @Derag. However, the values in the readback buffer are incorrect. 
Can this be because of the readback buffer description, that the numbers are not being interpreted correctly?

Comment: What values do you get? If you get only zeros you probably have some bug in code. If buffer you pass to `Map` have different type than `UAV` buffer that you read values can vary.
And I don't think that `D3D12_RESOURCE_DESC` should be problem here as long as `D3D12_RESOURCE_DESC::Width` is set to right size and `D3D12_RESOURCE_DESC::Format` is set to `DXGI_FORMAT_UNKNOWN`

Comment: The definition of the readback buffer is the same as what you suggested, the buffer which the shader actually calls (or in the example above "bufferB) has the following properties:
D3D12_HEAP_PROPERTIES defaultHeapProperties = { D3D12_HEAP_TYPE_DEFAULT,D3D12_CPU_PAGE_PROPERTY_UNKNOWN,D3D12_MEMORY_POOL_UNKNOWN,0,0 };
ThrowIfFailed(m_device->CreateCommittedResource(&defaultHeapProperties, D3D12_HEAP_FLAG_NONE, &buffersDesc1, D3D12_RESOURCE_STATE_GENERIC_READ, nullptr, IID_PPV_ARGS(&m_computeBuffer)));

Comment: What size of buffers did you set? And what types of data? (int, float...)